# USAR MAX y CASE al mismo tiempo SQLSERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenas a todos, creé una base de datos simple en SQLSERVER, la cual tiene empleados repetidos con distintas edades, ademas de una abreviación para ver si estaba soltero o casado. Lo que quiero es que me muestre la máxima edad por empleado, sé que no está correcto, pero solo lo hice por curiosidad, ya que no me había salido antes esa consulta.

La **query** usada es:

```
 SELECT nom_emp,MAX(edad_emp) 'Edad',(CASE estado_civi 
                                        WHEN 'C' THEN 'Casado'
                                        ELSE 'Soltero' 
                                        END 
                                        ) 'Estado Civil'
 FROM empleado a
 GROUP BY nom_emp,estado_civi
```

Como pueden ver me obliga a agrupar por estado civil lo cual hace que no necesariamente me aparezca el registro del empleado con mayor edad sino que pueda repetirse.

Por favor si pudieran resolverme esta duda, muchas gracias.

Comment: al menos deberías considerar en tu pregunta agregar información de ejemplo, de lo que tienes y lo que buscas.

Answer (score 1):

Antes que nada, imagino que tienes claro que una tabla de empleados que pareciera ser maestra con varios registros para un mismo empleado es un modelo inconsistente con la realidad. Obviando esto, te comento que las funciones de agregación, en este caso `MAX()` funcionan sobre los grupos, es decir, siempre te va a devolver el valor máximo de los registros agrupados, en tu caso: `nom_emp` y `estado_civi`. Si lo que buscas es el valor máximo a nivel de `nom_emp`, pudes hacer una subconsulta de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT  E1.nom_emp,
        E2.Edad,
        (CASE E1.estado_civi 
              WHEN 'C' THEN 'Casado'
              ELSE 'Soltero' 
        END) 'Estado Civil'
FROM empleado E1
INNER JOIN (SELECT nom_emp, MAX(edad_emp) 'Edad'
        FROM empleado
        GROUP BY nom_emp
    ) E2
    ON E2.nom_emp = E1.nom_emp
GROUP BY E1.nom_emp,
    E1.estado_civi,
    E2.Edad
```

Como puedes ver, el `INNER JOIN` apunta a una consulta agrupada únicamente por `nom_emp` y dónde recuperamos el máximo que estás esperando.

Answer (score 0):

Hubiera sido mejor usar un ejemplo que tenga un poco más de sentido.

Si solo quieres obtener la máxima edad por valor `nom_emp`, un simple `GROUP BY nom_emp` + `MAX(edad_emp)` es suficiente.

Pero si tu deseo es filtar y devolver solo los registros que corresponden a la máxima edad por agrupamiento `nom_emp`, pero incluyendo otros valores como `estado civil` de esos registros, entonces la forma más eficiente de hacerlo es usando la función ventana `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
select nom_emp,
       edad_emp as edad,
       case estado_civi
            when 'C' then 'Casado'
                     else 'Soltero' 
       end as [Estado Civil]
  from (select *,
               row_number() over (
                 partition by nom_emp
                     order by edad_emp desc) as rn
          from empleado) t
 where rn = 1
```

Otra interpretación posible de tu pregunta es que quieres ver todos los registros sin filtro, pero incluyendo en cada registro la edad máxima para el agrupamiento de `nom_emp`. En este caso, la forma más directa es usando la función ventana `MAX()`:

```
select nom_emp,
       max(edad_emp) over (partition by nom_emp) as edad,
       case estado_civi
            when 'C' then 'Casado'
                     else 'Soltero' 
       end as [Estado Civil]
  from empleado
```

Answer (score -1):

Tienes muchas formas de hacer la consulta que quieres, a mi, así de primeras se me ocurre:

```
SELECT nom_emp,edad_emp,(CASE estado_civi 
                                    WHEN 'C' THEN 'Casado'
                                    ELSE 'Soltero' 
                                    END 
                                    ) 'Estado Civil'
FROM empleado a
GROUP BY nom_emp,estado_civi
HAVING MAX(edad_emp)
```

Revisa también ese case, que me parece que está mal.